# Simulate Keyboard Event on Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, unmanaged

Please refer to the screenshot below:

The datetime control is a Compact Framework DateTimePicker, the numbered buttons are stndard Button controls.

Clicking on the arrow of the DateTimePicker displays a calendar control allowing the suer to select a date. However if the user clicks on any part of the selected Text date it is highlighted and can be amended using either the hard keys or the on-screen keyboard. I'm trying to emulate this functionality with my standard buttons.

I've have tried the following but currently this is only causing the DateTimePicker to lose focus.

```
    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0x0;
    const int VK_NUMPAD1 = 0x61;

    private void digitButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD1, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
        keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD1, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "keybd_event", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void keybd_event
    (
    byte bVk,
        byte bScan,
    int dwFlags,
        int dwExtraInfo
    );
```

[image: DateTimePicker Keyboard]

Answer (score 1):

I think you pointed out your problem, "...but currently this is only causing the DateTimePicker to lose focus".  I suspect your buttons are gaining focus and as a result are consuming the keystrokes.  You might try setting focus to the DateTimePicker before generating the keystrokes.  If that fails, as a last resort you can hard code to the control using SendMessage() to the window handle for the DateTimePicker, with WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP.

Comment: Thanks, setting focus to the DateTimePicker did partially solve the problem but didn't behave quite as intended. However it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following  - while I haven't tested it for your exact scenario, it does work in our .NET CF applications:

```
const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDED_KEY = 0x1;
const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
const int KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0x0;
const int VK_NUMPAD1 = 0x61;

private void digitButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD1, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD1, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}

[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "keybd_event", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void keybd_event
(
byte bVk,
    byte bScan,
int dwFlags,
    int dwExtraInfo
);
```

Answer (score 0):

keybd_event works fine, BUT you have to focus the datePicker first:

(on a form with one datePicker and 12 buttons (button1 to button12)):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Button)
            {
                int n = getButtonNumber((Button)c);
                if (n <= 10)
                    c.Text = n.ToString();
                c.Click += new EventHandler(c_Click);
            }
        }
        button11.Text = "<-"; button12.Text = "OK";
    }
    void c_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Button)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            int n = Convert.ToInt16( b.Text);
            digitButtonClick(n);
        }
    }
    private void digitButtonClick(int n)
    {
        byte vkInt = (byte)(0x30 + n);
        dateTimePicker1.Focus();
        keybd_event(vkInt, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
        keybd_event(vkInt, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
```

regards

Josef